# Where to find the builded artifactories using gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm coming from the Maven world, and I want to know where to find the local builded packages using gradle.

In maven these packages are published in the m2 repository. Is there something similar in gradle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle does not publish any artifacts in Maven-compatible repositories by default. In order to do that you'll need to use `maven-publish` plugin.

However, build results are actually cached in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory which is `~/.gradle` by default: `~/.gradle/caches`, `~.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`.